# Load Balancing : Does front end routing reduce server load?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes, load-balancing

I am little bit confused between front end routing and back end routing. I am using Angular JS and Laravel for one of my project.

I would like to get an advice or the way which I can reduce load balancing at the time of routing.

So , which would be the best way to use routing.

Front End routing or Back end routing.

I know SO is not for suggestions, but I googled a lot but could not get satisfying answers. That's why I am posting this question.

```
Route::post('users/{email_id}/{name}/{image_url} ', 'Userscontroller@index');
```

**Should I use this for routing or**

This code is in **app.module.ts** file,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';

/* Feature Modules */

import { ProductModule } from './products/product.module';

@NgModule({

imports: [

BrowserModule,

HttpModule,

RouterModule.forRoot([

{ path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },

{ path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }

]),

ProductModule

],

declarations: [

AppComponent,

WelcomeComponent

],

bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Should I use the above one ?

Any Help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will not find a concrete answer. I don't know which one is better. It depends upon what you are trying to do. It is better to measure and find out yourself. In my opinion routing alone will not have a huge impact on load balancing. Consider using Memcache, Redis etc and CDNs.

Basically speaking routing on the front end will have fewer number of HTTP requests and better for your server. You need to consider reducing the file size which reduces the number of TCP/IP extra round trips.

Also implementing some sort of non blocking asynchronous Process Pooling / Thread Pooling architecture and clamping the number of background worker on your back end will help to load balance.